# How to send and recieve xml with PHP ( SOAP web services)

Tags: php, soap

I want to connect to h1tps://ediwebs.sweatheranalysis.com.tr/sweatheranalysisediwebs.asmx?op=GetAnalysis and send with SoapClient or anything else this request

```
POST /sweatheranalysisediwebs.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: ediwebs.sweatheranalysis.com.tr
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Header>
    <AuthHeader xmlns="http://sweatheranalysis.com.tr/ediwebs/">
      <Partner>string</Partner>
      <Password>string</Password>
    </AuthHeader>
  </soap12:Header>
  <soap12:Body>
    <GetAnalysis xmlns="http://sweatheranalysis.com.tr/ediwebs/" />
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

the respond is similar to this:

```
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Header>
    <AuthHeader xmlns="http://sweatheranalysis.com.tr/ediwebs/">
      <Partner>string</Partner>
      <Password>string</Password>
    </AuthHeader>
  </soap12:Header>
  <soap12:Body>
    <GetAnalysisResponse xmlns="http://sweatheranalysis.com.tr/ediwebs/">
      <GetAnalysisResult>xml</GetAnalysisResult>
    </GetAnalysisResponse>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

how can i do it? i have try this but i'm getting error invalid login. using SOAPUI everything works fine

```
    try{
    $username = 'username';
    $password = 'password';

    $soapURL = "https://ediwebs.sweatheranalysis.com.tr/sweatheranalysisediwebs.asmx?WSDL";

    $client = new SoapClient($soapURL, [
    'stream_context' => stream_context_create([
        'ssl' => [
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
        ]
    ])
]);

    $auth = array(
        'Partner' => $username,
        'Password' => $password,
          );

    $header = new SoapHeader('http://sweatheranalysis.com.tr/ediwebs/','AuthHeader',$auth,'false');
    $client->__setSoapHeaders($header);

    $response = $client->__soapCall("GetAnalysis",$auth);
    var_dump($response);

    }catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Welcome on SO. It's hard to imagine really what our request looks like, compared to JSON. You can use [__getLastRequest()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastrequest.php) to get the XML request and compare it with your request in SOAPUI.

Comment: how to use __getLastRequest() in my code correct? i'm getting nothing and if set $client = new SoapClient($soapURL, ['trace'=>1,
    'stream_context' => stream_context_create([
        'ssl' => [
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
        ]
    ])
]); i'm getting a string with user and password nothing else

Comment: I just replace two lines here, you can let the others. Note that you can use `$client->GetAnalysis()` instead of `__soapCall`. See the [__soapCall documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php)
`$response = $client->__soapCall("GetAnalysis",$auth); var_dump($client->__getLastRequest());`

Comment: i got this: string(135) "
MyusernameMypassword
"

Comment: Try this in your Console (`php your-script.php`), or inspect the source in your browser. The XML is interpreted by your browser that's why you see only the strings. But the XML is there.

Comment: ok i got back this: <pre>string(135) "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://sweatheranalysis.com.tr/ediwebs/"><SOAP-ENV:Header><ns1:AuthHeader SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1"><ns1:Password>MyPassword</ns1:Password></ns1:AuthHeader></SOAP-ENV:Header><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:GetAnalysis/><param1>MyPassword</param1></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
"

Comment: You can see your XML. It seems you are using the default namespace `ns1` instead of `soap12`. It's supposed to be set from the WSDL I think.

Comment: not only this i expect to get back a temp link with weather analysis but the returned xml doesn't contain it... any suggestion?

Comment: The XML you got is the request. You can use [__getLastResponse](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastresponse.php) to see the XML response.

Comment: yes you are right. the request is different that i need how can i correct it?

Comment: Check the WSDL, set the namespace in your SoapClient (I'm not sure if it's automatic from the WSDL)

Comment: changed this line $header = new SoapHeader('http://sweatheranalysis.com.tr/ediwebs/','AuthHeader',$auth,'false');
     with $header = new SoapHeader('http://sweatheranalysis.com.tr/ediwebs/','AuthHeader',array('Partner' => 'username', 'Password' => 'password'),'false'); and worked... however namespace is the default not soap12. how can i chage it? i set it like this 'soap_version'=>SOAP_1_2 but didn;t work

Comment: If it works, why not left the default namespace?

Comment: there is not any serious reason but i'll try to fix it. thanks

Comment: Since the main problem is fixed, please answer yourself to the question and mark it as fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed this line    `$header = new SoapHeader('http://sweatheranalysis.com.tr/ediwebs/', 'AuthHeader',$auth,'false');`    with 
   `$header = new SoapHeader('http://sweatheranalysis.com.tr/ediwebs/', 'AuthHeader',array('Partner' => 'username', 'Password' => 'password'),'false');`    and worked